# Error while importing panda, but I already installed

Tags: pandas, numpy, import, importerror

I am getting the following error while trying to execute a python code trough a php one using Symfony:

I've already tried executing in the spyder environment, in sublime and in windows command prompt, and it works, only when I run the php code it return the error.

```
in import pandas as pd File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies)) ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

Comment: looks like you are missing `numpy` package

Comment: Well, since its running fine the other ways, I don't think I'm missing the numpy package, I already installed it

Comment: Do you have multiple Python installations on your machine? Another possibility I could think of is that the one that your Spyder and command line uses is different than the one your php code does

Comment: maybe, how can I find out?

Comment: Ok, I saw that I'm using anaconda of the following path   "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py"  if I transfer to C:, will it work?

Comment: It should. Just make sure use the installation that has all required packages